# How to Convert the complex notation into x, y-coordinates?

Tags: plotting

Convert the complex notation into x, y-coordinates; see also Accumulate and ListLinePlot.
[image]

I try to use the table to list all the summation value.( I suppose upper bounds N is 5)

```
plot1 = Table[{N,Sum[e^(2*Pi*I*n*Sqrt[2]),{n,1,N}]},{N,1,5}];
ListLinePlot[plot1];
```

But I just got an empty axis.
I think I need to convert the complex notation, I don't know how to convert it.
Could you give me some suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: See `ReIm`.....

Comment: Never use `N` as a variable, as it is a *function* returning the numerical value of its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

`Accumulate` can easy list all the part of the sums. `ReIm` can extract the `Re` and `Im` from the complex numbers.

```
pts = Table[Exp[2 Sqrt[2] π*I*n], {n, 1, 5}];
partSum = Accumulate[pts];
ListLinePlot[ReIm /@ partSum, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

**Method 2**

`ComplexListPlot` can deal with complex points directly.

```
pts = Table[Exp[2 Sqrt[2]*Pi*I*n], {n, 1, 5}]
partSum = Accumulate[pts]
ComplexListPlot[partSum, Joined -> True]
```

Or

```
complexPoints = Table[Sum[E^(2*Pi*I*n*Sqrt[2]), {n, 1, m}], {m, 1, 5}]
ComplexListPlot[complexPoints, Joined -> True]
```